# Create multiple database instances via Firebase CLI

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cli

I am looking into automating the deployment of a project that is made up of multiple functions that are triggers on multiple realtime database instances.

Using firebase deploy allows you to deploy both functions and database rules.
I have also created targets so i can deploy different rules for different database instances.

The only missing part of my automation is actually creating those different database instances via the Firebase CLI tool; Since deploying a trigger function to a specific database that doesn't exist will fail. Ideally i would like to make sure to create those database instances if they don't exist and then continue my deployment.

Is there a way to create different database instances via the CLI ?

Comment: I don't believe there's a way to do this, but you can always file a feature request: http://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features

Comment: > I have also created targets so i can deploy different rules for different database instances.

That sounds suspicious. The most common (and idiomatic) use-case for having multiple databases is for sharding users over database instances. In such a case, each database instance would have the same rules. It sounds a bit like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): what are you trying to accomplish by automatically creating database instances?

Comment: @DougStevenson That sounds like an answer. :-)

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I am using different instances of the database for different flavours of the same projects thats, in some unique case the database rule differs a bit and thats why im using different targets... that is actually working pretty well and not my problem, that was just to give context.

What i want to accomplish is to actually be able to add this to my CD build script to create a new database instance if a new flavour is needed.

Comment: I'd recommend using separate projects for that. As Doug commented: there is currently no API for creating database instances.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know when it was added, but this might be useful for others having the same question.

You can create a Firebase Realtime Database instance using the following CLI command:

```
firebase database:instances:create [instance-name]
```

I don't know why this isn't described in the CLI reference, but it is mentioned here: https://firebaseopensource.com/projects/firebase/firebase-tools/

Answer (score 0):

You can Create realtime database instance by firebase CLI using the below command

> `firebase database:instances:create -P <alias_or_project_id> <DBinstanceName>`

This Command work fine if you have paid plan.

For Free Plan it throw error:- `FirebaseError: HTTP Error: 400, Precondition check failed.`

**Note** : `<DBinstanceName>` should be alpha-numeric with hyphens.